# Newton's axioms and collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, differentiation, mathematics, singularities

Newton's axioms for point particles states that the velocity of a point particle is differentiable. However when two object collide there is a jump in their respective velocities. So is "ideal" collision something that is outside Newton's axioms or there is an extended concept of differentiability that functions with a jump counts as differentiable?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the concept of distribution (or generalized function).

Comment: **is there is an extended concept of differentiability that functions with a jump counts as differentiable?** Yes and no. No, in that differential calculus is based at all levels, around continuity of functions, but yes in that we can overcome  that using the delta "function", which is really a distribution  as referred to above: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function If  you are aware of this already, apologies

Comment: Thank you! No, I knew nothing about the mathematics of these objects. My goal is to axiomatize Physics (Hilbert's sixth problem). I have decided earlier to leave this forum completely however it was based on emotions. I will not leave the whole community because of a small fragment of it. Does anyone know anything about how to modify the axioms or the theory to be capable of expressing these collisions axiomatically?

Comment: You can just ignore the part about the axiomatization, it is more about Philosophy of Science that Physics. I will learn more about this delta function.

Comment: Well, it's not a forum ( in theory,)  but I take your point about the site turning into one, based on emotions, when questions arise about reality. Everybody (maybe not everybody, but nearly everyone), wants bedrock of some sort, and gets frustrated when it is not easy to find. The emotional part comes back to you though, but only if **you** let it. Look at my user name, I've been there :) There are plenty of worked examples of how we treat discontinuity in quantum mechanical potential wells, if you search on this site. Best of luck with it.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing as an "ideal" scenario is really an over-simplified one.

In reality, the objects colliding are *not* point particles.  They have volume.

Upon collision, the materials [deform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(mechanics)), causing them to slow down as they collide and press against each other.

In a perfectly elastic collision, this deformation would take all the kinetic energy from the objects, and store it internally in the deformations of the object.  Because it behaves elastically, as soon as the kinetic energy is gone, the objects will keep trying to force themselves back apart.  When we assume the energy goes fully back into kinetic energy, we see the velocities reversed.  It is essentially two springs touching.

This is not actually a discontinuity.  That part of the velocity/time curve would actually be a bit rounded, not a sharp point as is often shown in the analysis.

The only time you would get the discontinuity is for *infinitely* stiff elastic collisions, where they do not deform at all but still transfer the force back.  That is non-physical, so we only consider that when dealing with hypotheticals/idealized scenarios.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm getting to understand this. Pointwise objects and phenomena happening in 0 second are limit of possible Physical phenomena. So the mathematical model has to reflect that. The next natural question would be how to describe those phenomena but that is another topic.